Would Dicyanoacetylene Make a Good Flamethrower Fuel?
Ok so I've been working on researching a flamethrower fuel that can burn at extremely high heat so it melt through high heat resistant materials, such as Tungsten, Osmium, and so on. I've looked into https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyanoacetylene and it has the extremely high heat factor but I'm wondering if it would make a good fuel vs what we have used before in them, that being Gasoline, Diesel, & Napalm or would it be too dangerous to use in warfare?

Don't confuse a torch with a flamethrower. A torch emits a powerful, very hot flame. It is a tool first and for most, and like chainsaws it's short range limits it's use as a weapon. A flamethrower casts a stream of burning liquid over a distance. Not hot enough to weld or cut metal, but plenty hot to immolate anyone caught in it's path.

I'm actually not confusing a Flamethrower with a torch. I'm just talking about the fuel being used. I figured seeing as flamethrowers set things on fire, using a fuel that burns hotter would lead to better results and be effective against even Power Armor because it burns incredibly hot, well above the melting point of most materials in use at least by today's standards. But it's not looking like Dicyanoacetylene would be good for that purpose.

If you expect it to be able to 'melt' through all but the thinnest layers of materials like tungsten I'm kind of wondering what materials exactly you expect to make the flamethrower from?

Well it's not like the stuff is on fire while it's going through the flamethrower, it's only on fire once it leaves the actual device.

@Altarious: I see your point. Just use this liquid instead of hydrocarbons to make a flamethrower. Besides the instability (the liquid can detonate in the absence of oxygen, which is not a the case for gasoline), it may be too hot. Meaning the fire may vaporize all of the liquid before any can get to the target.

@KevinKostlan Exactly. Which is something I admittedly didn't think about until just recently when someone pointed out that sticking was necessary to actually transfer the heat more effectively. But I'm now thinking about using an Acid Thrower. As far as I know that doesn't need time to melt through anything, it just eats through it regardless of thickness to a degree, and looking into it there's a lot of different kinds of acids that work against all of my armors which is actually good. It means I can use something far more stable and common to fight both Powered Armor and Mechs.

@Altarious Ordinary acids, such as sulfuric acid, do not cause burns nearly as quickly as flaming oil. More extreme substances, such as chlorine triflouride, react so fast and violently that massive heat is generated. So they act like a flame-thrower.

Hah! Ok I didn't know they reacted like that, but that's good to know. I'm going to have to do more research tomorrow then.


Dicyanoacetylene freezes at 20.5 °C (68.9 °F), which would limit its use in combat to tropical regions.

It has a tendency to explode with minimal provocation.

It has a short shelf-life at normal tempeatures, polymerizing into a dark solid.

Which is why in practice welders use ordinary acetylene in oxyacetylene torches; the oxyacetylene flame reaches 3,500 °C (6,332 °F).



Ok, so would it make better sense to use it in a grenade or thermobaric bomb then? Or would it not make much sense to use it at all?

Why would you want to use in a hand grenade or thermobaric bomb? What does it buy you compared to ordinary composition B (for hand grenades) or much less exotic fuels, for example ethylene oxide, propylene oxide or even decane (for thermobaric bombs)? The sad truth is that dicyanoacetylene is a niche compound, with limited laboratory use and no industrial use, so that there is not much experience with it.

The high heat factor is the thing that makes it good, at least from what I've researched so I could be wrong, for melting through thick and high heat resistant armor. I'd use thermite for that application but I don't think it sticks to things.

High temperature alone is nowhere near enough to melt things. You also need to transfer sufficient thermal energy into the object. For a practical example, iron burns in air with a temperature of about 2200 °C (4,000 °F); the sparks you see flying from a metal grinder are burning steel, but when such a spark falls onto your skin it does have much effect, because although the temperature is high the spark is tiny and contains but little thermal energy.

Hmm so I'd need a way to make it so there's an adhesive of some kind to stick the burning material to the armor. Or looking into it, acid might be a better alternative for melting through thick armor. But I think that also has the same issues.

@Altarious more like you'd need to make a torch and direct the flame on the armor for a prolonged period of time. More likely you'd use an oxidizing flame to burn through, but that will still take time.

I actually did come up with a "Plasma Sword" that was basically a big beefed up blow torch attached to a suits on board reactor. But that felt too much like I was ripping off Gundam

@Altarious A sword would defeat the purpose of using a blowtorch, which would be to apply consistent heat to a location over time. No matter what you do, heat will take time to sink into the structure of armor and it's not really practical to try to accelerate it; if you need a quick kill then you want to look at a different mode of action.

Well that was the whole point of this Blow Torch Sword except that the Plasma was so hot it could do the job incredibly fast. Granted I felt like this wasn't really practical because, Plasma. Even if it was hot enough there's just better ways to have Sci-fi Swords in general like a Monomolecular Blade. We do actually have edge's that small, and with the right materials we could construct blades that thin but they'd have a lot of drawbacks as well.

Frame Challenge - you are thinking about Flamethrowers wrong
Flame throwers are never used to melt through things - even with a really high flame point, to melt through a solid piece of metal takes too long.
No, a Flamethrower has a number of key uses:

Psychological. All humans know what fire is and know what it is to be burnt. And burning to death was used as a punishment for heretics for a reason - it is a rather unpleasant way to go.

Soldiers know this - and this makes pushing into somewhere that is defended by Flame throwers difficult and it makes defending against Flame throwers equally so.
IIRC - in WW2, the British Crocodile tank (a Tank with a Flame thrower on it) was used to great effect to induce surrender. That is, the Tank would roll up, fire a burst of fuel at the target, without the pilot light going - soaking everything in flammable liquid - and giving the enemy time to contemplate what could happen next.

Liquids can get into all sorts of interesting places

If you have a particularly difficult bunker that you are trying to assault - whilst you might not have a gap enough for bullets, liquids can get places that bullets can't - like around a corner, through cracks etc. Even a Molotov Cocktail, thrown against the engine deck of a Tank can drip burning fuel into areas that are not meant to have burning fuel - and thus damage things like fuel lines or oil lines or even just the Air filter.

Sticky liquids create all sorts of problems for Infantry.

Yes, we are talking about Napalm - that most insidious of liquids. Having a gelatinous liquid that can be thrown far and sticks to the target as it is burning both does horrible things to the poor souls it is used against and drastically increases point 1 - the psychological horror of facing flame weapons.
Combine that with point 2 - and you have a very powerful combination of something that gets to places it shouldn't and then sticks there, whilst burning.

Heat expands to fill space

Every kid who has stood too close to the bonfire will know how you can feel the heat on your skin. This is why for Bunker clearing that Flame throwers in WW2 and up to Vietnam were used - even if you dont get direct contact with the people in the bunker - the Heat will force them to act - either retreat, exit, stop returning fire etc. Unless you are in some hermetically sealed power armour - the Heat is going to affect you.

The right fuel also does a good job of consuming the Oxygen in the environment and replacing it with toxic or noxious fumes

If you cant breath, you cant fight. It is a simple mantra - but with small enclosed spaces (where Flame throwers shine) if they have avoided the heat, the direct contact etc. can they still breath. Using up all the oxygen or just replacing it with enough carbon dioxide or other gases that are not good for us can render the opposition unconscious or dead in a short period of time.
TL;DR
You don't need a lot of heat in most cases for a Flame thrower - the damage they inflict isn't specifically about their heat output - it is about the ancillary effects of what fire does to the human body, especially in confined spaces and a liquids ability to flow into spaces that are not properly sealed.

I guess I figured Dicyanoacetylene would be a good idea because it burns at 9,000 degrees F. I can't think of much that can withstand heat that hot. But it does matter about exposure as well. If I could get it to stick to the suits that could be a good way of melting through them. I just don't know if anyway that could be done. Plus I'm not sure if the sticky material could survive the flames for long either

@Altarious that's why napalm is so nasty - the sticky stuff is the fuel so you don't have to worry about some form of glue melting.  Also white phosphorous on skin/clothing

It seems like the only reason flamethrowers are not longer in common use against fortifications is that they've been superseded by thermobaric ammunition and various bunker-busting shells, rockets, etc., all of which have greater range, and are far more precise than they would have been 50 years ago (a flamethrower of course doesn't need to be precise)

True. I honestly just need something that can melt through my settings armor. I honestly thought about a Sticky Thermite slurry but again not sure how viable that is or if it would be hot enough to do the job. I know Dicyanoacetylene is a liquid at room temperature but I now know it's also unstable and incredibly volatile and can only be used in places above 68° F. Granted I think after the apocalypse that wouldn't be an issue, but everything else bad about it will be an issue. So back to the drawing board for me.

This answer is correct - but by all of its points, dicyanoacetylene would still be an extremely effective flamethrower fuel. 1. it's a liquid and very notable as dangerous 2. it's not very volatile but very flammable, meaning it would do lots of harm in hidden places and be difficult to extinguish 3. more temperature makes more heat 4. because of the excess carbon, it would generate lots of carbon monoxide and other nasty combustion products.

@Altarious yes it'd be maybe a good alternative to thermite. Aka a specialised tool for "cutting" hard things in the field. But that's done by sappers or pioneer troops at 0 range. Or by artillery / heavy weaponry from afar. Flamethrowers do not play into this use-case

@Hobbamok true but this is a special case use because in this case these weapons are being designed to specifically destroy Powered Armor Suits and Mechs. If they can set the suit on fire and melt it as well as it's occupant then that's some less thing to worry about on a battlefield. With Mechs it would be to disable them for long enough to score a killing blow with some form of stronger Anti Mech Weapon. But it's not looking like Dicyanoacetylene would be good for that in a flamethrower fuel format at least. It might be better used in Missiles though.

@Altarious just to be sure,  dicyanoacetylene burns at 9000 degrees in oxygen,  not in air, so that's something to consider also

Wait there's a difference between those two things? Although I guess I that makes sense seeing as our atmosphere isn't pure oxygen. Yeah Acid is looking like a much better alternative for melting through PA.

@Altarious if what you need is a weapon that can cut through your setting's armor, you'd probably get more useful answers by asking another question targeted at that

@MJD True and I do plan on doing so, I just need to actually gather my thoughts and notes so I can ask the right question.

@Altarious uhm, that would have been a very, very important information in your question. Because you are NOT asking for a flamethrower. You won't melt a mech entirely and you won't set them (besides maybe the very first experimental generation) on fire. And you won't cook the pilot because the "brain" of a bilion-dollar machine will be isolated against all chemical, biological and other obvious threats (which includes heat because the mech itself will warrant that). Your only chance is to overheat the (reactor) cooling system, forcing a (partial?) powering down

@Hobbamok I mean I did ask if it could melt through High Heat Resistant materials that I have established as being a type of armor for Powered Armor Suits in another question. As it stands the question was simply, "Would this make a good flamethrower fuel" because that was the most important factor to know, it wouldn't make a good fuel regardless of its application so I can now focus on other tasks and weapons.

You're thinking the wrong way. Torches doesn't cut metal by melting it. The oxygen-acetylene flame heats the ferrous metal until red hot. When the metal is red hot, it's fairly reactive, so cutting oxygen is turned on. The cutting oxygen is a concentrated stream of pure oxygen gas. This sets the metal on fire - it's rusting really fast, and this is an exothermic reaction supplying heat energy, melting the material. In the molten state it's blown away by the oxygen stream.
Oxygen-acetylene cutting is not about the flame temperature. It's about supplying oxygen to a hot piece of metal.

In terms of storage issues, you may be able to make it on sight as needed.
Dicyanoacetylene can be synthesized from nitrogen gas and hot (~3000K) carbon.  Both of those store just fine and can be transported pretty easily.  With some good engineering the burning of the Dicyanoacetylene could potentially supply enough heat to fuel the reaction along with potentially using the cooling from liquid nitrogen evaporation to cool the condensation of the Dicyanoacetylene.  Seems at least scientifically feasible with a moderate amount of engineering with current technology.
